# conditional template kendo ui

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to use a row template in a Kendo UI grid only if a specific condition is met (e.g. a field on that row having a specific value)? If that condition is not met then it should not render the template and instead just render the row normally.

I don't want to specify the condition within the template itself because, unless I'm mistaken, I would also have to include the "default" html within the template definition if the condition is not met.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve, which doesn't work. For conciseness I've left out the other grid properties that aren't relevant to my question:

```
$("#divGrid").kendoGrid({
    rowTemplate: function (data) {
        if (condition) kendo.template($("#myRowTemplate").html(data));
        // else render row without the template, but how?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `kendo.template` returns a *Function* which needs to be called (with template data as argument) in order to return HTML code. So, for your example to work it needs to be modified like this:

```
$("#divGrid").kendoGrid({
    rowTemplate: function (data) {
        if (condition) {
            return kendo.template($("#myRowTemplate").html())(data);
        } // else render row without the template, but how?
    }
});
```

Now, unfortunately there is is no way to "*render the row normally*" as you've already specified `rowTemplate` function. You can only specify template (or string) which needs to be displayed in *else* condition:

```
$("#divGrid").kendoGrid({
    rowTemplate: function (data) {
        if (condition) {
            return kendo.template($("#myRowTemplate").html())(data);
        } else {
            return '<tr>Normal row</tr>';
            // or return kendo.template($("#myRowTemplate2").html())(data)
            // or return "<tr>" + data.name + ": " + data.age + "</tr>"
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is unfortunate, but thank you for your response and for fixing the issue with the missing parameter. Marking this as the correct answer.